# Error when i try Use EditText in map

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

i use map and when i try to use EditText the app crashed i used `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);` but get new Error

when i delete line with

```
 markerlocationtext.setText("Lat : " + CenterLOcation.latitude + "," + "Long : " + CenterLOcation.longitude);
```

the App work good

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
Marker marker;
TextView markerlocationtext;
LatLng CenterLOcation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     markerlocationtext =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
    SaveSettings sv = new SaveSettings(this);
    sv.LoadData();

    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (googleServicesAvailabile()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        iniMap();
    }

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();


    }


}

private void iniMap() {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public Boolean googleServicesAvailabile() {
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Connect to google play Services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mGoogleMap = googleMap;


    Location UserLocation= getlocation();
    new Location("phone");
    if(UserLocation== null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,getResources().getString(R.string.gpsoff),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    UserLocation= getlocation();
    gotolocationZoom(UserLocation.getLatitude(), UserLocation.getLongitude(), 15);



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

        return;
    }


    mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i)
        {



        }
    });


    mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMove() {

        }


    });




    mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {


           CenterLOcation = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;




        }
    });

     markerlocationtext.setText("Lat : " + CenterLOcation.latitude + "," + "Long : " + CenterLOcation.longitude);

}



private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.GpsDistable))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            });

    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}

    Location getlocation() {
    Location myLocation = null;
    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager != null) {


            myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (myLocation == null) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return null;
                }
                myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignored){

    }
    return myLocation;
}



private void gotolocationZoom(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);



}

public void geoLocate(View view) throws IOException {
    EditText editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    String LocationText = editSearch.getText().toString();

    if (LocationText.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(LocationText, 1);
        Address address = list.get(0);



        double lat = address.getLatitude();
        double lng = address.getLongitude();
        gotolocationZoom(lat, lng, 15);
    }
}

private void setMarker(double lat, double lng) {
    if (marker!= null)
    {
        marker.remove();
    }
    MarkerOptions options1 = new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Here")
            .position(new LatLng(lat,lng));

    marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeHyprid:
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

the Error show me when used without SetContentView

```
Process: com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi, PID: 6352
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:155)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
at aai.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got this Error with   `//  setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);`

```
Process: com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi, PID: 10899
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi/com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
at com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:56)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5287)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #32: Duplicate id 0x7f0c0082, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2427)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:77)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
at com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:56) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5287) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.activity_maps.xml"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/search"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    /><LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="130dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_map"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"

    android:text=" Set your Location "
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageMarker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/add_marker" />
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:hint="@string/where_you_want_to_go"
    android:text="@string/Search" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Find"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:onClick="geoLocate" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The layout file for your activity must be called right after super.onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
```

If not, your components declared before like your `TextView` cannot be binded to the view. That's why you are getting `NullPointerException` if you are not commenting this line

```
markerlocationtext.setText("Lat : " + CenterLOcation.latitude + "," + "Long : " + CenterLOcation.longitude);
```

Comment: i did  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);  but get secand error

Comment: Your Fragment declaration in XML has a different package name specified in tools:context than showed in the stack trace. Is it correct?

Comment: yes i corrected          tools:context="com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.activity_maps.xml"  but still same secand Error

Comment: @YasserAdmi `tools:context` doesn't do anything special to the code... It's actually removed from the code when the app is compiled

Comment: then why the Error i cant find i stuck here from 3 days

Comment: Try to move this problematic `markerlocationtext.setText` line **within** `onCameraIdle`, after you set `CenterLOcation`, or where `CenterLOcation` should not be null.